# EF Core, how can I query my DbContext when I only have a string variable containing a type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, entity-framework-core

I have two string variables `entityName` and `entityId`. I also have a `DbContext` with many data sets. I need to query the context using the type contained in `entityName` and I **know** that its value will match the name of the type of one of those data sets at this point. Here is my current approach (issue at the end):

```
var type = Type.GetType(entityName);
if (type == null) throw new Exception("Cannot find Type" + entityName);
var entity = await context.Set<type>().FindAsync(entityId);
```

The issue is that the compiler tells me I cannot use a Type variable `type` as a Type itself. Which makes sense, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I have also tried `context.Set(type)` which also give me compiler errors.

Comment: Everything is possible. For which purpose do you need that? I ask to avoid wasting our time and provide  best solution.

Comment: It's a super long story as to why I need this in this case. Trust me that I normally access my context with a strongly typed `DbSet<>` like a good boy haha...

Answer (score 4):

I found a method of `DbContext` that met my needs, and I had to revise my logic to get the type from a string a little. Here is the resulting code:

```
var assembly = typeof(Person).Assembly; // Person is arbitrary, I'm just getting assembly the contains my models
var type = assembly.GetType(entityName); // entityName must include namespace
var entity = await context.FindAsync(type, Guid.Parse(entityId)); // key type must match
```